# How to connect to SQlite using cl-dbi

Tags: sqlite, lisp, common-lisp, cl-dbi

Tried:

> (defvar *connection*
>         (dbi:connect :mysql
>                      :database-name "test"
>                      :username "nobody"
>                      :password "1234"))

Result:

```
System "dbd-sqlite" not found
   [Condition of type QUICKLISP-CLIENT:SYSTEM-NOT-FOUND]
```

Can anyone point to an example of use of cl-dbi with Sqlite3?

Comment: `:mysql` which database are you trying to use? And do you have the appropriate lisp library installed?

Comment: If you want to connect to sqlite3, it doesn't seem sensible to use `:mysql` as an argument.  Maybe try to modify the example call from the README?  It's an example, not a magic “do what I mean”.

Comment: Ah, yes.  correct db.  Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (cl-dbi:connect :sqlite3 :database-name "db.db")

Use `:sqlite3` as the driver name.

You had a clue on the README: https://github.com/fukamachi/cl-dbi#using-dbiwith-connection-to-ensure-connections-are-closed (which, accordingly, could be more explicit)

```
(dbi:with-connection (conn :sqlite3 :database-name "/home/fukamachi/test.db")
  ;;                        ^^^ sqlite3
  (let* ((query (dbi:prepare conn "SELECT * FROM People"))
         (query (dbi:execute query)))
    (loop for row = (dbi:fetch query)
          while row
          do (format t "~A~%" row))))
```

and also a pointer on the documentation here: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/databases.html#connecting-to-a-db (the Mito ORM uses cl-dbi).

Have fun!