# How can I open a SQLite DB by AutoLisp,and create a SQLite DB and insert deta by AutoLisp?

Tags: sqlite, autolisp

I want to use Autolisp to control SQLITE DB,so how can I open a SQLite DB by AutoLisp,and create a SQLite DB and insert deta by AutoLisp?

I haved search in www and line group.But I don't find any deta.So I ask the question st here.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60142337/how-to-connect-to-sqlite-using-cl-dbi